# Can JavaFX Embeded app talk to remote mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Just a quick question. Is it possible to have an JavaFX app embeded in a web page talk to a remote mysql database. My boss has asked me to look into this because he's considering using Java for various parts of the in-house system we're building. It's been a few years since i last looked at Java and google doesn't seem to provide any definitive answers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While this can work technically, modern browser environments are pretty hostile to embedded Java applications (i.e. your users may find it difficult to run your application).  You will also need firewall rules on your network allowing connection from the client to the MySQL server.  Instead, maybe build a [self-contained JavaFX application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) which communicates over http (e.g. via JAX-RS or web sockets) to a Java server which communicates to your database.

Comment: That link was a very interesting read and i've booked it for my own future reference but unfortunately in this case my boss is adamant that everything is available via the web browser, so self contained packages that have to do be downloaded and installed is just no good for this situation. Thanks for taking the time to offer your advice though, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes This is possible . Your javafx ui will run on clientside(browser) and talk to server which can connect to remote database. This approach will segregate your ui at client and data at server side.

The only irritation I feel it will ask all client to update to java8 version to run java fx

Comment: Would I need to allow remote access to the database via plesk before a connection will be allowed?

Comment: No that will be taken care at backend